# How to trigger NgxsOnInit?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I want to trigger an action when the user first visit my site. What's the best way in doing this with ngxs? I found out there's this thing called NgxsOnInit but I don't know how it is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the NgxsOnInit is an interface that you implement in your state class.

a good use for this is dispatch actions when the state loads the first time.

```
// auth.actions.ts
export class CheckSession() {
  static readonly type = 'auth/check-session';
}


// auth.state.ts
import { State, Action, NgxsOnInit } from '@ngxs/store';

export interface AuthStateModel {
  token: string;
}

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: 'auth',
  defaults: {
    token: null
  }
})
export class AuthState implements NgxsOnInit {

  ngxsOnInit(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    ctx.dispatch(new CheckSession());
  }

  @Action(CheckSession)
  checkSession(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: CheckSession) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But if you need to get some info based on the url, it's better to create a route guard that dispatches the action and then uses `store.selectOnce` to retrieve the value you need from the state.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Store, ofAction } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { GetProject } from './project.action';
import { ProjectState } from './project.state';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const projectId = route.paramMap.get('projectId');

    // we call the store which downloads the project, we then wait for the action handler to return the project
    return this.store.dispatch(new GetProject(projectId)).pipe(
      // we convert the project to a boolean if it succeeded
      map(project => !!project),

      // we catch if the GetProject action failed, here we could redirect if we needed
      catchError(error => {
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

// app routes

```
{ path: 'project/:projectId', loadChildren: './project#ProjectModule', canActivate: [ProjectGuard] },
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just inject `ActivatedRoute` in the State class to get url params?

Comment: @StevenLiekens No, you would not want to do that.  Similarly to services, states persist from when they load until the app goes away.  You never want to inject ActivatedRoute into things like services.